# Java Exception Naming Conventions

Tags: java, exception, naming-conventions

In Java, is there a semantic difference between using "**Illegal**" (as in `IllegalArgumentException`) versus "**Invalid**" (as in `javax.activity.InvalidActivityException`)?

During the course of an assignment it became useful to write a subclass of `IllegalArgumentException` to represent a series of input characters that cannot be tokenized, and I'm wondering whether convention says to use `InvalidTokenException` or `IllegalTokenException`.

The only difference I can find so far is that `java.lang` seems to prefer "Illegal" while `javax.*` prefers "Invalid". However, there is also `java.security.InvalidParameterException` which is a subclass of `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can have **legal** usage of an API and still have **invalid** data; it is all semantics.

Comment: But the IllegalArgumentException appears to cover both illegal API usage and invalid data.

Answer (score 2):

`javax.activity.InvalidActivityException` is inherited from  `java.rmi.RemoteException` and you probably don't want this dependency. See also [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activity/InvalidActivityException.html)

EDIT both Invalid and Illegal are used synonymously it makes no differency in semantics, just the technical issues mentioned above.

EDIT: From Postgres [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/error-style-guide.html) Section 45.3.14. Tricky words to avoid:

**Illegal**.  "Illegal" stands for a violation of the law, the rest is "invalid". Better yet, say why it's invalid.

Comment: He's talking about names, not extending the InvalidActivityException.

Answer (score 0):

I was just pondering the same question. There is no documentation I know of explaining any distinction between "illegal" and "invalid". If I were try to tease out some semantics, perhaps "illegal" could be considered a broader category meaning "not permitted", while "invalid" represents some value that doesn't meet some validation constraints or isn't recognized.

Thus in one of those old text-base adventure games, `turn("qwerty")` would pass a value that is both illegal and invalid, as `"qwerty"` is not a valid direction to turn. However `turn("left")` would represent a valid value, which might or might not be a "legal" direction to turn depending on whether there was a wall to the left of the current player's position.

In that light, `IllegalArgumentException` represents any argument that is not-permitted for whatever reason, whether the value in itself is otherwise valid.

I stress that this explanation is something completely of my own reasoning, and may or may not reflect established conventions. But until someone comes up with a better conceptualization, this is the approach I'm going to take in my libraries.

See also the discussion at [illegal vs invalid](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/illegal-vs-invalid.2108931/), which provisionally makes a distinction similar to the one I just made. It also [points out](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/illegal-vs-invalid.2108931/post-10554703) that those who chose the existing usages "are not always sensitive to shades of meaning" to begin with. Thus I would imagine that in many cases 'illegal" and "invalid" were used interchangeably.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, IllegalArgumentException should only be used when you want to signal the incorrect use of an API method call. What it appears you are describing is a scenario when the API has been used incorrectly, so I think an IllegalArgumentException would be the better choice.

Comment: Did you mean `IllegalStateException` for the second "IllegalArgumentException"? If not, I'm really confused...

Comment: AFAIK that is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @DR - you would be correct. Thanks for the formatting improvement, btw.