# Naming conventions of Java exceptions: Illegal vs. Invalid

Tags: java, exception, naming-conventions

I recently thought about the naming conventions of Java exceptions, regarding exceptions starting with "Invalid" and such starting with "Illegal". When looking through the `Exception` classes, at a first glance it looks like the "Illegal..." exceptions are all subclasses of `RuntimeException`, i.e. unchecked exceptions. However, there are for example classes like `InvalidParameterException` and `InvalidPathException`, which start with "Invalid" but are subclasses of `IllegalArgumentException`, which is a subclass of `RuntimeException`. There are also examples the other way around, for example `IllegalAccessException` or `IllegalClassFormatException`, which are checked exceptions.

So my assumption with checked/unchecked exceptions seems to be *invalid*. Does anyone know the naming convention behind this? Does a naming convention for this exist at all?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364217/java-exception-naming-conventions), which however focuses more on how to name an own subclass of `IllegalArgumentException`.